# How to calculate the current value plus the next item that enters the array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still beginner with JavaScript and ReactJS.

I have a list that shows some numbers that the user typed. What I would like to know is how do I add the current value that exists in my array `+` the new value that the user typed.

For example, if there is a number 5 in my array, and the user types the number 3, I want to add these values and show them to the user. It is easier to explain through an image:

And [here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-galileo-etnjp?file=/src/index.js) my code.

[image]

**Add New Value**

```js
import React from "react";

import { AppContext } from "../../providers";

const Add = () => {
  const { dispatch } = React.useContext(AppContext);
  const [transaction, setTransaction] = React.useState(0);

  const onChangeValue = (e) => {
    setTransaction(+e.target.value);
  };

  const onTransactions = () => {
    if (transaction === 0) return;
    dispatch({
      type: "ADD_TRANSACTION",
      payload: transaction
    });
    setTransaction(0);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>New transaction</h3>
      <div>
        <div>
          <input type="number" value={transaction} onChange={onChangeValue} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style={{ margin: "20px 0" }}>
        <button type="button" onClick={onTransactions}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Add;
```

**List Results:**

```js
import React from "react";

import { AppContext } from "../../providers";

const List = () => {
  const { state } = React.useContext(AppContext);

  return (
    <div>
      {state.transactions.map((transaction) => (
        <div>
          <span>
            -You add ${transaction}, your balance is: ${transaction}
          </span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Thank you very much for any help!!!

Comment: use Accumulator   `Array.reduce()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep a total balance and a running balance:

```
const initialState = {
  balance:0,
  transactions: []
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TRANSACTION":
      return {
        ...state,
        balance: state.balance + action.payload,
        transactions: [{value:action.payload,balance:state.balance+action.payload}, ...state.transactions]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

You can just render these in your list view

```
const List = () => {
  const { state } = React.useContext(AppContext);

  return (
    <div>
      {state.transactions.map((transaction) => (
        <div>
          <span>
            -You add ${transaction.value}, your balance is: ${transaction.balance}
          </span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively simple in your local `transaction` state, as you can access the current value of `transaction` in your `setTransaction` call by passing it a function rather than a value.

```js
const onChangeValue = (e) => {
  setTransaction(state => state + e.target.value); // `state` here is the value before your update
};
```

Whatever you return from this callback will become the new value of `transaction`.

By the looks of it, the fact that you're storing these values in an array in context is irrelevant, unless of course you intend to use those existing values as your starting state for later transactions (i.e., multiple *submit* events without resetting to zero in between).

If that's the case, and if I'm understanding you correctly, then you'll want to map over each item in your context state and add the locally stored *transaction* to each of those values.  Something like:

```js
const onTransactions = () => {
  if (transaction === 0) return;
  dispatch({
    type: "ADD_TRANSACTION",
    payload: state.transactions.map(val => val + transaction)
  });
  setTransaction(0);
};
```

This'll add the new value to each of your values in your context (assuming your context has a handler that's doing what I think it's doing).

Answer (score 0):

Just declear another variable for total Amount of all input Sum

```
const [transaction, setTransaction] = React.useState(0);
const [totalAmount, setTotalAmount] = React.useState(0);

const onChangeValue = (e) => {
    setTransaction(e.target.value);
    setTotalAmount(ParseInt(totalAmount) + ParseInt(e.target.value))
};
```

your render JXS will be

```
<span>
        -You add ${transaction}, your balance is: ${totalAmount}
      </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declear another variable for total Amount of all input Sum

```
const [transaction, setTransaction] = React.useState([]);
const [totalAmount, setTotalAmount] = React.useState(0);
const onChangeValue = (e) => {
     let newtransaction = transaction
     newtransaction.push({value: e.target.value, amount: totalAmount + 
     ParseInt(e.target.value)})
     setTransaction(newtransaction);
     setTotalAmount(totalAmount + ParseInt(e.target.value))
};
```

your render JXS will be

```
transaction.map(trans => 
    <span>
            -You add ${trans.value}, your balance is: ${trans.amount}
          </span>
)
```